# "This device is not working" - Wifi Issues

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04

When I try to enable my Broadcom drivers in the Additional Drivers section on my Macbook Air 2013, I am not able to finish enabling them because it says "this device is not working."

I have no option to use an ethernet cable, usb modem, or anything of the sort.  I need help on trying to use wireless internet, and if I can't use WiFi Ubuntu will be useless for me.

How do I fix this?

When I put in `lspci`, I got this:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:15.0 DMA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Serial IO DMA Controller (rev 03)
00:15.4 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Serial IO GSPI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
04:00.0 SATA controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a801 (rev 01)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 156b
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 156b
06:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 156b
06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 156b
06:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 156b
06:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 156b
07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 156a
```

I also put in, `lspci -nnk`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI [8086:1604] (rev 09)
    DeviceName: SATA
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI [106b:011b]
    Kernel driver in use: bdw_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1626] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [106b:011b]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Broadwell-U Audio Controller [106b:011b]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller [8086:9cb1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:15.0 DMA controller [0801]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Serial IO DMA Controller [8086:9ce0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Serial IO DMA Controller [8086:9ce0]
00:15.4 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Serial IO GSPI Controller #1 [8086:9ce6] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Serial IO GSPI Controller [8086:9ce6]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 [8086:9cba] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:9c90] (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 [8086:9c92] (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:9c94] (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9c98] (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:9c9a] (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9cc3] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9ca2] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller [8086:9ca4] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
02:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
    Kernel driver in use: bdc-pci
    Kernel modules: bdc_pci
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0117]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
04:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a801] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a801]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:156b]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
06:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:156b]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
06:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:156b]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
06:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:156b]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
06:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:156b]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
06:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:156b]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
07:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:156a]
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `lspci`. I'm sure either Pilot6 or Chili555 will be able to provide you an answer, but they'll need that info.

Comment: Please expand @AndroidDev 's request just a bit: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and also: `rfkill list all`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Ok I updated the description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is your wireless device:

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03) Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
```

If you have the installation USB or DVD, insert it and and drill down to: `pool/restricted/b/bcmwl` and drag `bcmwl-kernel-source` to your desktop. Do the same with `pool/main/d/dkms` and drag `dkms` to you desktop. Then install:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour Glad it's working.