# No wifi options Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - running on an old MacBook Air

Tags: networking, wireless, macbook

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an old MacBook Air that had ceased working (pinwheel of death, OS X wouldn't boot). Wiped OS X from the machine on install. The idea was to get some additional usage out of a machine that otherwise would be headed for the trash. Ubuntu works just fine, and connected to the wifi during install.

On restarting, however, it now says "No network devices are available", and can't see wifi network(s).

Please note that its a Mac and only has USB and Thunderbolt ports–so cannot connect to ethernet.

I'm not very techie, and new to Ubuntu, so any suggestions please be plain and practical. Thanks!

UPDATE:

02:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01) Subsystem: Apple Inc. Airport Extreme [106b:00e9] Kernel modules: bcma 03:00.0 PCI Bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Port [Cactus Ridge] [8086:1547] (rev 03)

SUGGESTED SOLUTION:

> The needed driver bcmwl-kernel-source, is on the installation media.
>   Please check here: askubuntu.com/questions/835475/…

DIDN'T WORK:

```
FATAL: Module wl not found in directory lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic" . Wifi still not working.
```

FOLLOW-UP

> What version is the deb file?
>   bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb? Note it
>   should be xx-0ubuntu3. If not, I will un-dupe the question and propose
>   an answer. – chili555 1 hour ago

RESPONSE:

> It appears to be 0ubuntu1~1.1

FURTHER UPDATE:

Did as suggested here:

> I suggest that you download this package on some other computer and
>   put it on a USB key or similar.
>   http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
>   Transfer it to the Ubuntu computer to some convenient place such as
>   the desktop. Now, in the terminal:

The "arch" command result was was fine with following result:

```
x86_64
```

I then followed the further commends in terminal and got following result:

```
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
```

FIXED!

Thanks guys, the last fix suggested worked fine, and my Ubuntubook is now connected to the internet. Good job.

Comment: We can gather the needed information the fastest and easiest from the terminal. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run this command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` By the way, don't get rid of the install DVD or USB quite yet, we might need it. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, done that. It says: "02:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)

Comment: Next line: "Subsystem: Apple Inc. Airport Extreme [106b:00e9]", Next line: "Kernel modules: bcma", Next line: "03:00.0 PCI Bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Port [Cactus Ridge] [8086:1547] (rev 03)"

Comment: 02:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01) Subsystem: Apple Inc. Airport Extreme [106b:00e9] Kernel modules: bcma 03:00.0 PCI Bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Port [Cactus Ridge] [8086:1547] (rev 03)

Comment: The needed driver bcmwl-kernel-source, is on the installation media. Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/835475/this-device-is-not-working-wifi-issues/835493#835493

Comment: Ok, thanks. Did all of the instructions at the link you provided using USB with Ubuntu on. Unfortunately after the final stage ("sudo mod probe wl") it resulted in this: "FATAL: Module wl not found in directory lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic" . Wifi still not working.

Comment: What version is the deb file?  bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb? Note it should be xx-0ubuntu3. If not, I will un-dupe the question and propose an answer.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, the failure to build issue is a bug that was fixed in later versions of *bcmwl-kernel-source*. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1724863

I suggest that you download this package on some other computer and put it on a USB key or similar. http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb Transfer it to the Ubuntu computer to some convenient place such as the desktop. Now, in the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Note any errors and post them. If there are no errors, load the module:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

NOTE: This assumes yours is a 64-bit installation; check:

```
arch
```

If the terminal returns x86_64, then the 64-bit package referenced above is correct. If not, then this is the package you need instead: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_i386.deb